# I have duplicate home page, How Can I fix it?

Tags: seo, sitemap, xml-sitemap

Using some website audit tools I found that it says a lot that I have a duplicate content like so:

```
https://example.com/
https://example.com/index.php
```

in my sitemap I only have:

```
<url>
  <loc>https://www.example.com/</loc>
     <xhtml:link rel="alternate"
               hreflang="it"
               href="https://www.example.com/"/>
    <xhtml:link rel="alternate"
               hreflang="en"
               href="https://www.example.com/en/index.php"/>
</url>
```

I don't know why google splits it up into two links.
How can I fix it?

(PS `https://www.example.com/en/` and `https://www.example.com/en/index.php` doesn't give me this problem )

Comment: You should never be using `index.php` in your URLs.  It shouldn't be in any links on your site.  It shouldn't be in your sitemap.   `index.php` is a directory index that power the page for the directory URL.   The first rule of directory index is that you never talk about directory index.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller Thanks for the advice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you set up a 301 redirect using .htaccess to redirect `https://example.com/index.php` to `https://example.com/` and add a canonical tag containing `https://example.com/` then you don't really need to worry what the website audit tools say.

After doing this you can remove the `https://example.com/index.php` from your sitemap if you wish.